# server sent event using jsp not working

Tags: java, html, ajax, jsp, jsp-tags

i want to achieve server sent events using jsp but it's not working,
 My code is as given below but it not even displaying date also

date.jsp

```
  <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
  <%
    response.setContentType("text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

  %>


  <%
    Date date = new Date();
    out.write(+date.toString()+);
    out.flush();
    try {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    %>
```

and my ex.html code is as fallows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
     <h1>Getting server updates</h1>
     <div id="result"></div>

     <script>
     if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
     {
         var source=new EventSource("date.jsp");
         source.onmessage=function(event)
         {
             document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
         };
     }
     else
     {
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support   server-sent events...";
     }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### OUTPUT IS:

Getting server updates

---

not displaying the date also...

I am using tomact server,is there any problem in the code

Comment: `not working`  ?? can you please tell whats happening ? Error ? Exception ?

Comment: `out.write(+date.toString()+);` is invalid for starters.

Comment: out.write(+date.toString()+); is invalid for starters what it mean how can i over come it

Comment: @manoj Remove the `+` symbols... What do you think those are doing?

Comment: after removing + also not working

Comment: what's `EventSource`? And what's worse, why are you using scriptlets?

Answer (score 0):

you should use something runnable like body onLoad or button onClick listeners, 
you should use correct path to your jsp or servlet(placed not inside WEB-INF folder), 
you should use correct event data format, with "data:" prefix and "\n\n" suffix.

ex.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onLoad = RegisterSSE()>
          <h1>Getting server updates</h1>
          <div id="result"></div>
          <script>
              function RegisterSSE()
              {
                  alert("wtf");
                  if(typeof(EventSource) != "undefined")
                  {
                      var source = new EventSource ("http://localhost:8080/web_war_exploded/date.jsp");
                      source.onmessage = function(event)
                      {
                          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br/>";
                      };
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support   server-sent events...";
                  }
              }
          </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

date.jsp

```
<%
    response.setContentType("text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

    Date date = new Date();
    out.write("event: server-time\n\n");
    out.write("data: "+date.toString() + "\n\n");
    out.flush();
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

and after all you should use google, your question is nothing new, please see links below:

[java-servlet-and-server-sent-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466713/java-servlet-and-server-sent-events)

[push-notification-for-java-web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474273/push-notification-for-java-web-app)

[how-push-notification-java-servlet-for-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010701/how-push-notification-java-servlet-for-web-application)